# Is there a unity-like "Sticky edges" option to prevent the cursor from hopping across displays so easily?

Tags: macos, display, mouse

When moving the cursor towards a clickable item near the middle edge of a multi-monitor display, it is easy to move "too far", causing the cursor to jump to the other display. This is disorienting.

Does OS X (I'm on El Capitan if it matters) have a similar feature?

More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html#Sticky_Edges